# Vue.js CSS change button onClick to href not working

Tags: css, vue.js

In a SinglePageApp, I need to use a `<button>` tag rather than an `<a>` tag 5 I am using UKit

the `<a>` tag would be :

```
<a type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-link" href="#events"><events</a>
```

But writing the  tag this way , does not work

```
 <button @click="location.href='{{ url('events') }}'" class="uk-button uk-button-link">EVENTS</button>
```

note : I see an ESLint error ..  [js] ';' expected

Answer (score 3):

@webnoob answer is correct , however it seems that it's not working in a single page application : I get a scopelocation undefined error..

SO I am using a method :

```
      <button @click="goToEvents()" class="uk-button uk-button-link">EVENTS</button>
```

and

```
methods: {
    goToEvents: function () {
        location.href='#events'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To do an onclick with Vue, you would do it like this:

```
<button v-on:click="location.href=url('events')" class="uk-button uk-button-link">EVENTS</button>
```

You can also use `@click="location.href=url('events')"`

Take a look at [Vue Event Binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) for more information.

If you're within a form and don't want the form to be posted as well, you would need to also add in `.prevent` so it would become `v-on:click.prevent="url('events')"`

You only use `{{ }}` (mustache's) when you're rendering content i.e text. When you're within an attribute which you want to use dynamic values in, you would prefix the attribute with `:` so, for instance, if you wanted to add some dynamic text in a data attribute, it would become `:data-something="myDataProp"`

Comment: just tried it ... not working Is it because I am in a singlepage app   scope.location is undefined

Comment: Yes, I almost suggested you wrapping the redirect into a method but it wasn't really in scope of the question. Glad you got it working.